# Asking For Mercy vs. Repentance On Shabbath

Tags: shabbat, repentance-teshuvah

Being that one is not allowed to do teshuvah tataah on Shabbath, is asking for mercy for committing a melacha or sin on Shabbath the same as repentance? For example, “Hashem, I ask for your forgiveness for performing speaking business on the Shabbath” vs. “Hashem I ask for your mercy for speaking of business matters on Shabbath.” One is asking for forgiveness while the other is asking for clemency.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.288.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/131210/27180